# What does AdditionalProps = {} mean?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following code snippet is from `@types/reactjs`:

```
export type PropInjector<InjectedProps, AdditionalProps = {}> = <
  C extends React.ComponentType<ConsistentWith<React.ComponentProps<C>, InjectedProps>>
>(
  component: C
) => React.ComponentType<
  Omit<JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<C, React.ComponentProps<C>>, keyof InjectedProps> &
    AdditionalProps
>;
```

To me, it looks very complicated and very difficult to read. However I would like to know, what does this mean:

```
AdditionalProps = {}
```

Does it mean `AdditionalProps` has to be an empty object?

Comment: Looks like specifying a default value to me, but I'm not really a typescript person so someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bas van der Linder is right. This is default value.

Comment: What is a default value? So the default value of `AdditionalProps ` is `{}`?

Comment: `AdditionalProps` is a generic type, with a default value of type `{}`

Comment: So, is `{}` a unit type with no properties?